# Delete words that match the pattern on the string

Tags: php, string

I have to filter a string according to words similar to the pattern. 
I need to delete words that match the formula:

```
<?php
$string = 'armin van burren yummy';
$pattern = 'a%n v%n b%n';

//result: Yummy

$string = 'Beyonce - love on top';
$pattern = 'b%e';

//result: Love on top

$string = 'Ed Sheeran - Shape of You';
$pattern = 'e_ s_____n';

//result: Shape of You



?>
```

Do you have any idea how to get this result, maybe there is some function in php. I tried to search, unfortunately I didn't find any information. Thank you for all the help and examples

Comment: Did you check : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php ?

Comment: Please take some time to at least make your own attempt.  There is plenty of documentation out there on string-matching and regular-expression functions.

Comment: Use `preg_replace` to replace them. Here's your first pattern. https://regex101.com/r/FjFsho/1 figure the rest out!

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me, is it possible to limit the amount of foreach for this code (performance is concerned)?

```
function filterlike($arr, $like){
                if ($arr && $like){
                    $like = preg_replace('/_{1,}/','.*', $like);
                    $like = preg_replace('/%/','.*', $like);
                    $like = explode(' ', $like);
                    $filter = array();
                    foreach ($arr as $a){
                        foreach ($like as $l){
                            $a = preg_replace('/'.$l.'/', '', $a);
                        }
                        $filter[] = $a;
                    }
                    return $filter;
                }
 }

print_r(filterlike(array('armin', 'van', 'burren', 'jummy'), 'a%n v%n b%n'));
print_r(filterlike(array('armin', 'van', 'burren', 'jummy'), 'a___n v_n b____n'));
```